# Can you use the Abort Switch option after seeing the other players' cards for that register?

Tags: robo-rally

Do I need to declare I am using the abort switch card before we flip for the current register, or can I call to use it after seeing everyone's cards for that register? The description implies the latter.

> Once each turn, you may replace one of the Program cards you reveal with the top card from the deck. If you do, you must replace the Program cards for all your remaining registers the same way that turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear, but I'd say yes, you can see the other players' cards.

The rules explicitly say that everyone reveals their cards at the same time, so if you reveal a card, everyone else's are visible too. (I'd probably try to avoid spending much time looking around at everyone else's moves and figuring out conveyor belts and so on, though!)